# Remove hyperlinks in Visual Studio “Design” view

Tags: visual-studio-2010, design-view

I can’t seem to find a way of doing this, but it’s such a simple thing that it must be possible. What I want to do is unlink some text that is currently a hyperlink, but I want to do it from within the “design” view in Visual Studio. Any ideas?

The reason is that I have a really huge document that I need to delete all the links from and doing it in “source” view is taxing forever. I wouldn’t normally use “design” view for anything, but I figured it’d be easier to do something like this visually—seems I was a little wrong with my assumption!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I eventually figured out how to write a regex for the find/replace dialog that did what I wanted to do in seconds.